# Can't append Mysql Column

Tags: mysql, append

So I'm new to MySQL, but I've been working on this for a few hours now and no matter how I write it, I can't append anything to a column in my database. I've been using the w3schools template but I can't seem to get it to work. I am checking the contents of the database with the following code, which works. I will remove the password and url. I am trying to associate a bunch of texts which will be updated, like 123, 234, 345, to a row (their email).

```
<?php
mysql_connect('mywebsite.com', 'myusername', 'mypassword') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mydatabase') or die (mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from emails");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['myemail'];
?>
```

Now that works, and if I give it a value from PHPmyadmin, it shows up.
Here is the snippit of the other file, which is supposed to give/change the value of it. (This is inside of another PHP file)

```
mysql_connect('mywebsite.com', 'myusername', 'mypassword') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mydatabase') or die (mysql_error());
$sql="UPDATE emails SET myemail = CONCAT(myemail, 'testappend')";`
```

Now, that code runs whenever I run a program, and everything but the mysql area works. It doesn't seem to do anything at all, I couldn't get it to append, and I changed it to update the data completely and that didn't do anything either.

When I insert a value with PHPMyadmin, it does this, and it updates everything fine.

```
INSERT INTO  mydatabase.emails (
myemail
)
VALUES (
'test2'
);
```

So "emails" (the real name) is a table, which has currently 1 email (myemail), and that has a text value of 'test1' right now.

Edit: I changed it to CONACT but that isn't the problem apparently

Comment: do you run `mysql_query($sql)` at all?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `CONCAT` instead of `CONACT` in your code

If that doesn't work, what does placing `echo mysql_error()` at the end of your code return?

Comment: If that wasn't the issue I think you should try to execute the actual query by placing `mysql_query($sql)` after `$sql="UPDATE emails SET myemail = CONCAT(myemail, 'testappend')";`

Comment: I added echo mysql_error() and placed the whole thing into a new PHP file by itself, when I run it, nothing happens. It's entirely blank, and it doesn't update.

Comment: I did that, and now I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in todb.php on line 6, which is because of the echo mysql_error() - I took it out and put mysql_query($sql) in, and it still doesn't do anything. Is it possible the whole thing is mixed up, like I'm trying to add to the wrong thing (table/row) - As I said, this is really my first time with MySQL. Here is what it looks like from PHPmyadmin

https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/0/AACD-8BXwQw9yPGEMi76jde4EfSKz-vkH4SC2MzkAacwRQ/10/79794232/png/32x32/6/_/1/2/g5H.png/8nHt9cTWzROw4D5lteebxocWINS-klewOakkcgOZsPQ?size=1280x960&size_mode=2

Comment: That link to your PHPMyAdmin screenshot is not a public URL but I guess your code must be something like this:
`<?php
mysql_connect('mywebsite.com', 'myusername', 'mypassword') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mydatabase') or die (mysql_error());
$sql="UPDATE emails SET myemail = CONCAT(myemail, 'testappend')";
mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_error();
?>`

Comment: Sorry, http://uput.in/YFP - That's actually what I'm doing, where the program will have your email and then after it uploads the image, it associates it with your email